# Dynamic Filtering in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to understand how dynamic filtering works.
What I know about it is that , say there are 2 tables A (with million rows) and B (with 10k rows).
Now while performing a join between A and B if a predicate is applied on B , then via Dynamic filtering we can avoid full scan for A.
This helps in less data getting shuffled.
My questions are :

- 1) Does this automatically happen in spark or do I have to enable
  some property?
- 2) Is there a way through which I have to provide my    filters ,
  before the sql is executed ?
- 3) Are there any downsides to    this    approach?
- 4) Any link that    provides an explanation on this ?

Comment: I do  not think the term dynamic filtering is correct

Comment: Haven't come across dynamic filtering in Spark sql. Can you point to the documentation where you got to know about this.